# Bounds on Eigenvalues After Skew-Symmetric Perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, eigenvalues

Consider two matrices $\mathbf{J} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\mathbf{L} = -\mathbf{L}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. I am trying to upper bound the eigenvalues of their sum:

$$\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{J} + \mathbf{L}$$

in terms of the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{J}$. If it helps, the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{J}$ are distinct and have negative real part.

It is easy enough to show that the eigenvalues of the *symmetric part* of $\mathbf{A}$ are equal to the eigenvalues of the symmetric part of $\mathbf{J}$, but can something be said about the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{J}$?